# Error on execution due to setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, spinner

I've tried to execute this code in my phone and in a AVD but unfortunately the app tp2 has stopped however the gradle build finished with no errors.
Could someone help me with that please ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner spinner;
EditText field;
Button addBtn,UpdateBtn,clearBtn;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> films = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    field = findViewById(R.id.field);
    addBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    UpdateBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.updatebtn);
    clearBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);

//ADAPTER
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,films);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            field.setText(films.get(i));
        }

    });
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            add();
        }
    });clearBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            delete();
        }
    });
    UpdateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            update();
        }
    });

}
//methods
private void add(){
    String film=field.getText().toString();
    if(!film.isEmpty() && film.length() >0){
        adapter.add(film);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        field.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Ajoute" + film, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rien a ajouter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private void update() {
    String film = field.getText().toString();
    int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if (!film.isEmpty() && film.length() > 0) {
        adapter.remove(films.get(pos));
        adapter.insert(film,pos);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Modifie" + film, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Pas Modifie" + film, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
private void delete(){
    int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if(pos > -1){
        adapter.remove(films.get(pos));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Supprime" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        field.setText("");
                    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Rien a supprimer" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}


}
```

It seems to be working but actually it crashes. The activity crashes and I can't find out why because nothing else (id) is displayed. Sorry for the bad english

Comment: What error message do you get in the Logcat?

Comment: You need more null checks and you can probably declare your class members final since they are initialized in the onCreate.

Comment: check my answer .always try to post the error logs @Ahmed

Comment: dont forget to mark my answer @Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setOnItemClickListener` cannot be used with a Spinner. Use this `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead.

Comment: @Ahmed you are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

Try cast field to EditText

```
field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field);
```

if there's still a problem please share the error message